# Exporting map to PDF, fix polygon bleed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, symbology, export, pdf

I'm trying to export my map. But ArcGIS generates PDF (or other) maps that is not the same as in the layout view. I have polygons that is filled with a pattern, and this pattern is drawn over the entire page (outside of the polygon).

Have anyone experienced this problem before? And is there a way I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: My first guess is that you may have a topological error in one of you polygon features, try running the repair geometry tool on the polygon layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, this is probably a topological error.  You may use the [Repair Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000) tool to repair the polygon feature.

[Polygon fills bleed over or fill entire page when printing or exporting](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31413)